# min of col x with condition from table teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to find the minimum of a date column, where another condition is met

i.e with table :

```
ID     date  condition   ... 

1      3/15   0
1      4/15   1
5123   5/15   1
5123   7/15   1
5123   1/15   0 
2      2/15   0
2      1/15   1
2      1/15   1
```

I want a single line within the select statement, without filtering the rest of the table, to produce :

```
ID    date
1     4/15 
5123  5/15
2     1/15
```

I have tried :

```
min( date with condition = 1 )

min( date where condition = 1 )

case when   condition=1  then min(date) end
```

but am getting a syntax error.

Comment: For each ID, or do you want just one row? (Add some more sample data, different id's, same dates etc, and adjust the wanted result.)

Comment: `SELECT MIN(date) FROM table WHERE condition = 1` ?  But what actual query did you try?

Comment: If an ID has no row with condition = 1, do you still want that ID in the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*I don't want to filter the rest of the table*", use a `case` expression to do conditional aggregation:

```
select id, min(case when condition = 1 then date end)
from tablename
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

For each Id if you want the minimum date, you need to use the GROUP BY

```
SELECT ID, MIN(Date) AS Date
FROM TableName
WHERE Condition = 1
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to qualify I would like to produce this with a single line within the select statement

Comment: @user124123: The above is a single line select statement only, it doesn't contains any sub-query.

Comment: I don't want to filter the rest of the table.